# Fix AttributeError in python code

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I got some code that I think should work, but I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "c:/users/proxtr~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpgtrnqo.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       qgis.path.insert(0, 'C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python') AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'path'

This is the code

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

#""" Put your code here and remove the pass statement"""
#"Edit this path if you have a different version than QGIS 2.14.1"
qgis.path.insert(0, C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python)
#The path is between these 2 comments"
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

extent = layer.extent()
width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()

layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

for layer in layers:
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())
path='C:\tif'%layer.name%'.tif'
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(path)
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,width,height,extent,layer.crs())
```

Comment: So, in your code you're importing 3 times anything from qgis.core? You're also mixing Windows and GNU/Linux paths, which, for sure, won't work. First give your code a review and then post a question. BTW, yo can just paste your code inside your question and click the button with curly brackets ("Code Sample") to format it.

Answer (score 2):

`qgis` module has no attribute `path`, I guess you wanted to do `sys.path.insert()`

So it should be:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python')
```

Remember to pass your path as a string with " ".

Comment: Paths need forward slashes `'/'`, `'\\'` escaping, or raw string notation `r""`